# Group subcategory in category

Tags: meteor

How can I group subcategory in category that they belongs to? For example category is ICT and I want only subcategory (such as laptop,komputer,etc.) that belongs to ICT display in the dropdown.

addItem.html

```
 <template name="addItem">
    <div class="form-group">
                <select class="form-control" name="category_name">
                    <option selected> --Category-- </option>
                    {{#each category}}
                        {{> downCategory}}
                    {{/each}}
                </select>   
                </div>
            
                <div class="form-group">
                <select class="form-control" name="subcategory_name">
                    <option selected> --Subcategory-- </option>
                    {{#each subcategory}}
                        {{> downSubcategory}}
                    {{/each}}
                </select>   
                </div>
    </template>


<template name="downCategory">
    <option id="{{_id}}">{{category_name}} </option>
</template>

<template name="downSubcategory">
    <option id="{{_id}}">{{subcategory_name}} </option>
</template>
```

addItem.js

```
Template.addItem.helpers({
    category: function(){
        return Category.find({});
    },
    subcategory: function(){
        return Subcategory.find({});
    }
});
```

Comment: Could you please provide the documents' structure of the collections `Category` and `Subcategory`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would imagine that you'll need to have a hierarchical data structure for your categories, you can do this easily when creating categories have an optional `parentId` field on your category, and then query for subcategories by the id of the category your subcategories belong to.

addItem.html

```
 <template name="addItem">
    <div class="form-group">
                <select class="form-control cat-select" name="category_name">
                    <option selected> --Category-- </option>
                    {{#each category}}
                        {{> categoryOptions}}
                    {{/each}}
                </select>   
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                <select class="form-control" name="subcategory_name">
                    <option selected> --Subcategory-- </option>
                    {{#each subcategory}}
                        {{> categoryOptions }}
                    {{/each}}
                </select>   
                </div>
    </template>


<template name="categoryOptions">
    <option id="{{ _id }}">{{ name }} </option>
</template>
```

addItem.js

```
Template.addItem.helpers({
    category: function(){
        return Category.find({});
    },
    subcategory: function(){
        var id = Session.get('selectedCategory');
        return id ? Subcategory.find({parentId: id}) : false;
    }
});

Template.addItem.events({
    'change .cat-select': function(e, t) {
        //... get the selected option and set a var called carId then set a session var to make it available 
        var catId = $(e.target).val() || false;
        Session.set('selectedCategory', catId);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I have solved the question. And it can be reference to anyone who had the same problem.. :)

```
addItem.html


<template name="allCategory">
        <div class="form-group">
            <select class="form-control category-selection" name="name_category">
                <option selected> --Category-- </option>
                {{#each category}}
                    {{> downCategory}}
                {{/each}}
            </select>   
        </div>

</template>

<template name="allSubcategory">
            <div class="form-group">
            <select class="form-control subcategory-selection" name="name_subcategory">
                <option selected> --Subcategory-- </option>
                {{#each subcategory}}
                    {{> downSubcategory}}
                {{/each}}
            </select>   
            </div>


</template>


<template name="downCategory">
    <option id="{{_id}}"> {{name_category}} </option>
</template>

<template name="downSubcategory">
    <option id="{{_id}}"> {{nama_subcategory}} </option>
</template>
```

addItem.js

```
    enter code here

Template.allCategory.helpers({
    category: function(){
        return Category.find({});
    }
});

Template.allCategory.events({
    "change .category-selection": function(e, t){
      return Session.set("category", $("[name=name_category]").val());
    }
  });

Template.allSubcategory.helpers({
    subcategory: function(){
        return Subcategory.find({
            category_id: Session.get('category')
        });
    }
});
```